# How should I retape an inside drywall corner when the wall is heavily textured?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

We just bought a house built in 1992 and need to retape the ceilings in some of the rooms where the ceilings are angled and the tape is coming loose. We have already removed the popcorn ceiling to do so.
The issue I foresee is that in some areas where the ceiling meets the walls, they need to be retaped - but the wall is very heavily textured.

Do we need to do something specific to repair this so we don't have an untaped corner?

Would it be smart to just finished the molding at the top that they didn't extend in to the living room to make the job "easier"?

Comment: Pictures would be helpful.

Comment: Finish as normal and then recreate the texture over the repaired areas. If you find it easier to put up crown molding instead of texturing then do that but still repair the drywall.

Answer (score 1):

If the tape on the wall is fine, one option is to cut the existing tape along the seam between the ceiling and the wall. Remove the half from the  ceiling as repair ceiling as needed.

Then, to finish, run a bead of caulk along the seam and paint.

Tape is always preferred, but I've used caulk for inside corners in lieu of tape many times and (knock on wood) it's worked just fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

To repair  drywall tape that has come loose you will need to remove the tape sections with a utility knife. Next replace the tape you removed by liberally troweling joint compound into and around the incision. Rip a piece of drywall tape from a roll and push it onto the wet compound. At about a 20 degree angle and with gentle pressure , pull your drywall blade across the tape. You want to keep the tape in place , but press it as flat to the wall as possible. If done correctly compound will squish from the tape edges. Repeat 2-3 times leaving as little compound under the tape to adhere it to the joint. Let dry overnight and knock any burs or ridges off. Apply second layer as the first only using a wider blade. The idea is to feather each layer a few inches wider than the one before it so as to make the repair as unnoticible as possible. BTW the reason for using drywall tape is that it strengthens the gypsum panels joints making them less likely to open or crack. Regarding your idea to cover damaged tape with molding (maybe crown?) that would work, but it's a matter of personal taste. Either idea will work wich do you like or prefer?

Comment: Your answer doesn't address anything about the texture, just general how to tape a corner.

Comment: No, but it wasn't an answer